# How do I stop one audio track when another one starts? (with only a text link)

Tags: javascript, audio

I was trying to play a list of audio files on the same web page with only a text link as play button, and I found the following solution, which works really perfect for me: 
(thanks @linstantnoodles for this script!)

```
<audio id="song1" preload='auto'>
<source src='song1.mp3' type='audio/mp3' />
</audio>

<audio id="song2" preload='auto'>
<source src='song2.mp3' type='audio/mp3' />
</audio>

<a href="javascript:null()" id="song1-control">Listen</a>
<a href="javascript:null()" id="song2-control">Listen</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
// List of audio/control pairs
var playlist = [{
    "audio": document.getElementById('song1'),
    "control": document.getElementById('song1-control')
}, {
    "audio": document.getElementById('song2'),
    "control": document.getElementById('song2-control')
}];

for (var i = 0; i < playlist.length; i++) {
    var obj = playlist[i];
    var audio = obj.audio;
    var control = obj.control;
    // returns a closure
    var listener = function (control, audio) {
        return function () {
            var pause = control.innerHTML === 'Pause';
            control.innerHTML = pause ? 'Listen' : 'Pause';
            // Update the Audio
            var method = pause ? 'pause' : 'play';
            audio[method]();
            // Prevent Default Action
            return false;
        }
    };
control.addEventListener("click", listener(control, audio));
}
</script>
```

My only problem with this code is, that if one song is playing, and I start a second one, both are playing at the same time. I've tried many ways to get this problem fixed, but none of them did work - how do I need to adapt it, so that the first one pauses or stops when a second one starts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. When a new audio is started, loop through the `playlist` array to find all the audio elements that are not the one that just got started and stop them.

Here is an example:

```
....
var method = pause ? 'pause' : 'play';
audio[method]();
if(!pause){
    playlist.forEach(function(pl){
        if(pl.audio !== audio){
           pl.audio.pause();
           pl.audio.currentTime = 0;
           pl.control.innerHTML = 'Listen';
        }
    });
}
....
```

Comment: Thank's for your fast reply!
It didn't work with `pl.audio.stop()`, but it worked well, when I changed it into `pl.audio.pause(); pl.audio.currentTime = 0;`. The only deficit is, that the textlink-playbutton from the first file still is set on "Pause" - is there a possibility to reset all the previous buttons to "Listen"? I tried to change the innerHTML-values, but then I couldn't pause the tracks anymore...

Comment: @modestus I've edited my answer to address all that.